# Returning range of cells based on user input

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script which looks up a list of student's teachers based on a start time and stop time. It's combining Google Sheets cell-based formulas and a Google Script.

In the Spreadsheet, I have a database sheet - `db` - which is a static list of students and their teachers in order by column. The second sheet - `tchrLookup` - uses data validation and an `INDEX - MATCH` search to pull data from the database into the lookup.

The script analyzes the lookup page to (eventually) build email notifications to the teachers matched in the search. My arrays are all returning correctly, except for the last one. I can't figure out where my logic is buggy.

**Script**

```js
  function findTchr() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sheet.getSheetByName('tchrLookup');

  // Loop through each row and get the teachers assigned as an array
  var range = ss.getRange(2, 2, ss.getLastRow()-1, ss.getLastColumn());
  Logger.log(range.getValues());

  var cells = range.getValues();
  for(i=0;i<cells.length;i++) {

    // Get the start and stop values for each row
    var start = cells[i][0];
    var stop = cells[i][1];

    // Determine the number of columns to return
    var tchrsToGet = stop-start+1;
    Logger.log("Start: " + start + ", Stop: " + stop);
    Logger.log("# of cols to get: " + tchrsToGet);

    // Return teachers based on start/stop time
    var tchrs = ss.getRange(2, start+3, 1, tchrsToGet);
    Logger.log(tchrs.getValues().toString());
  }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the log file after running the script.

[image: Log entry]

You can see the original values array at the top. The final log entry is returning the third teacher incorrectly and I can't figure out why. I have a **[test spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZVu90K8oWQs82T8whr0Vb8IX5fso6MwcAh3wBKofUBs/edit?usp=sharing)** with edit permissions so you can see how the whole things is intended to work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 22:

```
var tchrs = ss.getRange(2, start+3, 1, tchrsToGet);
```

The row parameter is never changing.  The code is always checking row 2.  Change to:

```
var tchrs = ss.getRange(i+2, start+3, 1, tchrsToGet);
```

The first parameter is the start row.   The start row should increment with the value of `i` in the `for` loop.

Comment: Oh, wow...I didn't even think to try that. I had tried just using `i` for the start value, but it would return an error for the range selection. Thanks for taking a look at it.